# Ban user from chat

Tags: node.js, lwp-useragent

I own a chat site that consists of several user interfaces that depend on socket and nod js. There is an order to ban the user and block his phone through the user agent, but the user can change the user agent and log in, what is the solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The site depends on the user agent, and they can change the user agent. I want it to depend on MAC address by javascript or node js